# How to remove sort & direction keys from the pagination links and apply the order specified in controller action

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I'm using paginator component of `paramType` is `querystring`, and specified multiple order in action before taking results from `$this->paginate()` as like this

```
$this->paginate['order'] = array(
    "field1" => "Asc",
    "field2" => "Desc",
    "field3" => "Asc",
);

$this->set('results', $this->paginate('ModelName'));
```

When i click on page 2 link it's generating a url like `?page=2&sort=field1&direction=Asc` I want to remove the sort key from query strings and need to fetch the results by applying order i've specified.

Could anybody help me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: We might have to backport https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/2753 into 2.5

Comment: Does it support multiple sorting @mark ?

Answer (score -2):

As seen on documentation, you can override the paginate method:

```
/**
 * Overridden paginate method - group by week, away_team_id and home_team_id
 */
public function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page = 1,
    $recursive = null, $extra = array()) {

    $recursive = -1;
    $group = $fields = array('week', 'away_team_id', 'home_team_id');
    return $this->find(
        'all',
        compact('conditions', 'fields', 'order', 'limit', 'page', 'recursive', 'group')
    );
}
```

Or this, taken from documentation:

**Control which fields used for ordering**

By default sorting can be done with any column on a model. This is sometimes undesirable as it can allow users to sort on un-indexed columns, or virtual fields that can be expensive to calculate. You can use the 3rd parameter of PaginatorComponent::paginate() to restrict the columns that sorting will be done on:

```
$this->Paginator->paginate('Post', array(), array('title', 'slug'));
```

This would allow sorting on the title and slug columns only. A user that sets sort to any other value will be ignored.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

Comment: This isn't the answer i'm looking for :(